# How to get pending transactions with using geth or other client?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs, pending-transactions, clients

I would like to get pending transactions with using geth.

And I tried to use 'web3.eth.pendingTransactions' on geth console.
So the geth returned '[]'.

```
> web3.eth.pendingTransactions
[]
```

But I visited [Etherscan's pending transactions page.](https://etherscan.io/txsPending)

They could display pending transactions.
It was displayed 'A total of 74,945 pending transactions found' and the transactions list.

Why can they gain pending transactions with elapsed time ?
Is this possible with using geth or other client ?
Or is this the software of their own developing ?

I'd like to get pending transactions with using geth via web3.js (or with using other client via other node.js library).

Comment: is your geth client already 100% sync with the main network?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the pending transactions you need a node that you're running on your own because this type of action requires a lot of resources.

You can run your own Geth node and wait until it is synchronized. When I want to run a Geth node on the main net and query for the transaction pool, I usually start it like this.

Download the Geth binary and rename it as `geth.bin`.

Then run:

```
./geth.bin --datadir=./chaindata \
    --rpc --rpcapi="eth,net,rpc,web3,txpool,personal,debug,account" \
    --rpccorsdomain='*' --port 30303 \
    --txpool.globalslots=250000 \
    --txpool.globalqueue=50000 \
    console
```

The important parts are:

- `--rpc` enables rpc requests, so you can connect with web3.js / web3py / ...
- `--rpcapi` defines what APIs are available over RPC; the important one in this case is `txpool` which enables a Geth specific API to query for the transaction pool; this is usually faster than the standard one. Documented [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool) as a non-standard RPC method;
- `--txpool.globalslots` and `--txpool.globalqueue` increases the number of slots available for the pending transactions; otherwise it will ignore other pending transactions once it reaches a specific number (by default 4096)
- `console` it will open a console where you can run commands in.

After you start Geth like that and wait for it to be synchronized, you can run commands inside the open console.

`txpool.status` [doc](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool_status) will display a statistic of pending and queued transactions. Pending are the ones that you care about, might be included in the next blocks if the miners choose to add them.

```
> txpool.status
{
  pending: 1234,
  queued: 4321
}
```

`txpool.content` [doc](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool_content) will display details about each transaction in the current lists.

```
> txpool.content
{
  pending: {
    0x0216d5032f356960cd3749c31ab34eeff21b3395: {
      806: {
        blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        blockNumber: null,
        from: "0x0216d5032f356960cd3749c31ab34eeff21b3395",
        gas: "0x5208",
        gasPrice: "0xba43b7400",
        hash: "0xaf953a2d01f55cfe080c0c94150a60105e8ac3d51153058a1f03dd239dd08586",
        input: "0x",
        nonce: "0x326",
        to: "0x7f69a91a3cf4be60020fb58b893b7cbb65376db8",
        transactionIndex: null,
        value: "0x19a99f0cf456000"
      }
    }
  },
  queued: {
    0x976a3fc5d6f7d259ebfb4cc2ae75115475e9867c: {
      3: {
        blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
        blockNumber: null,
        from: "0x976a3fc5d6f7d259ebfb4cc2ae75115475e9867c",
        gas: "0x15f90",
        gasPrice: "0x4a817c800",
        hash: "0x57b30c59fc39a50e1cba90e3099286dfa5aaf60294a629240b5bbec6e2e66576",
        input: "0x",
        nonce: "0x3",
        to: "0x346fb27de7e7370008f5da379f74dd49f5f2f80f",
        transactionIndex: null,
        value: "0x1f161421c8e0000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I could use TxPool.

However, I don't know why there is a difference in the number of pending transactions between my geth node and etherscan.io.

For example,
The number from my geth node is 4281.
But that on etherscan is 72385.

Comment: Make sure to increase the number of txpool slots with `--txpool.globalslots`.

Comment: Now number of pending transactions is 67862 on my geth node.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*I'd like to get pending transactions with using geth via web3.js (or with using other client via other node.js library).*

In order to get pending transactions using web3.js, the required steps are:

```
npm i web3
```

Create a file getPendingTx.js

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
const getPendingTransaction = () => {
  web3.eth.getPendingTransactions((err, pendingTxs) => {
    console.log('Pending transactions are: ', pendingTxs);
    // In case if you want to return pendingTxs
    return pendingTxs;
  });
}
```

[Example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#id68)

[Web3 Pending Transactions Reference](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#getpendingtransactions)